# Couchdb view to selecting products using another key

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, couchdb

I' ve a big list of products (they are ink cartidges and toner) stored in a couchdb, for every document i've got several fields, and one particular field called "models" that is a multidimensional array like this:

```
"models": {
"Brother": {
  "HL": [
    "5200",
    "5240",
    "5240 DN",
    "5240 DNLT",
    "5240 L",
    "5250 DN",
    "5250 DNHY",
    "5250 DNLT",
    "5270 DN",
    "5270 DN 2 LT",
    "5270 DNLT",
    "5280 DW",
    "5280 DWLT"
  ]
},
"": {
  "MFC": [
    "8460 DN",
    "8460 N",
    "8860 DN",
    "8860 N",
    "8870 DW"
  ],
  "DCP": [
    "8060",
    "8065 DN"
  ]
},
"Lenovo": {
  "": [
    "LJ 3500",
    "LJ 3550",
    "M 7750 N"
  ]
}
```

},

I've to do several things with this data, starting with fixing a little problem that i've got while they was written, if you look at the example that i've posted, the second and the third brother serie has an empty array string instead of the "brand" value that should be "Brother"... i've many records that miss the "brand" key for certain series, and this should be set to the previous serie brand, i.e. the "MFC" serie should has the top level key set to "Brother" that is the key of the previous serie.
I can do this using a view in couchdb?

After doing that i need to obtain a list of unique models using another view with every product associated to them.. in other words i've to select all of my products using the last level of the multidimensional array "models" as key (including also brand and serie values as secondary result for futher sorting and filtering) and all the products that contain that certain model as value.

An output like this:
    key: "Brother, HL, 5200" - value: "id_product1, id_product2, idproduct3, etc."

Before i start to reading all documentation present on the earth can someone explain me if this thin is at least doable?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: properties in json objects are not in determined order.  How would i know that the `""` top level attribute should go with `"Brother"` instead of `"Lenovo"`?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what should be

Comment: Okay, But *why* should it belong to `"Brother"` instead of `"Lenovo"`,  Keys in json do not occur 'after' one another, `""` is not after `"Brother"`,  Should I assume that, when I see a key that is `=== ""`, I can just guess `"Brother"` is what's meant?  Should I pick one at random out of the top level keys?